# Save file after using sed command

Tags: files, sed, replace

I am using following command to replace `yyyymmdd` to `YYYYMMDDHH24MISS` in my file:

```
sed -e 's/\('yyyymmdd'\)/\('YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'\)/g' filename
```

After I run the command in PuTTY, it displays the file with replaced values, but they do not reflect if I `more` the file.

I tried using `-i` , but it says

```
sed: illegal option -- i
```

Can someone please suggest how do I replace the given code in multiple files and save them?

Comment: How you're using the `-i` option? Can you please update your question with the line that contains the `-i` flag please?

Comment: The `-i` option is not POSIX conformant: what system / flavor of Unix is the `sed` command being run on (Linux? BSD? OSX?)

Comment: As steeldriver said, you need to tell us i) what operating system you are connecting to and ii) show us the _exact_ command you ran. Also, this has nothing to do with your issue but you don't need the `\(` or the `'` or any of that. Your command can be written simply as `sed -e 's/yyyymmdd/YYYYMMDDHH24MISS/g` (you can even omit the `-e` on some systems).

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
sed 's/yyyymmdd/YYYYMMDDHH24MISS/g' filename > changed.txt
```

Or, to keep the same filename:

```
sed 's/yyyymmdd/YYYYMMDDHH24MISS/g' filename > changed.txt && mv changed.txt filename
```

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549

Answer (score 3):

Your `sed` command only sends its result to the standard output.
You would have to redirect it in a subsequent command (NOT in the same command, like `sed 'sedcommand' file > file`, as this would erase the file before processing it).

You also can pipe the commands to `ed` instead of using `sed` :

```
for file in $filelist ; do
  echo -e '%s/yyyymmdd/YYYYMMDDHH24MISS/g\nw' | ed $file
done
```

which substitutes on every line (`%`) then, after a separating newline (`\n`), writes the modified file in place (`w`).

Comment: `sed(1)` and `ed(1)` are mostly compatible, command-wise.

Answer (score 3):

use `-i` option with `sed` command:

```
sed -ie 's/\('yyyymmdd'\)/\('YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'\)/g' filename
```

Comment: Not only did the OP write that the `-i` option is not supported, this example wouldn't do what you claim it does.

Comment: The `-i` option (which the user has already said they can't use) takes an argument on most systems (even on Linux).  That argument is the backup suffix to use for the original data when doing an in-place edit. You will notice that your command creates a file called `filenamee` (note the extra `e` at the end).  Always test commands that you post here.

Comment: sed -ie 'expression' file works fine on Ubuntu